# Resolve two EFI issue installation

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, grub-efi

I installed my entire Ubuntu OS on HDD along with it EFI. I already has a EFI in Local Disk C but there was not enough space available to install Ubuntu in there. I wanted to know that will it cause any problem.

Moreover , I wanted to know how to confiugre my dual boot such that every time I see the menu of selecting between Windows10 & Ubuntu.

Thank You

Comment: Only the 1st stage bootloader is installed in the ESP (EFI System Partition). Even the small default partition creating alongside the Windows installation is enough for MANY additional OSes. You don't install Ubuntu in said partition, you install Ubuntu in its own partition(s).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Comment: If both systems are installed in UEFI boot mode and Windows fast start up is off, you just need to run `sudo update-grub` Fast start up sets hibernation flag & then Linux will not fully mount the NTFS partition. Windows may turn fast start up back on with updates.

Answer (score 0):

EFI is designed so that there should be a single EFI partition per device for all operating systems.  However, it should not cause problems that you have more than one EFI partition on your system.

In order to get GRUB on every boot, you must change your UEFI settings in your motherboard so that the volume with Ubuntu/GRUB is the first boot priority.  You will need to consult with the documentation for your computer's motherboard for this step because it is a function of your motherboard's firmware.  It's not related to Ubuntu or any other operating system and the process varies between different models of motherboards.